# Trimming video with the help of mp4Parser

Tags: android, video, mp4parser

I am trying to trim or cut a video for specific time, Example:- Video-1 which is of 30 Sec trim to Video-2 10 sec (0.10 sec to 0.20 sec). I am able to do this and able to play this video but in the end of video it gives error saying- `Sorry! cant play this video.`

```
public static void main(String args) throws IOException {

        Movie movie = new MovieCreator()
                .build(new RandomAccessFileIsoBufferWrapperImpl(
                        new File(
                                "/sdcard/Videos11/"+args+".mp4")));

        List<Track> tracks = movie.getTracks();
        movie.setTracks(new LinkedList<Track>());
        // remove all tracks we will create new tracks from the old

        double startTime = 3.000;
        double endTime = 9.000;

        boolean timeCorrected = false;

        // Here we try to find a track that has sync samples. Since we can only
        // start decoding
        // at such a sample we SHOULD make sure that the start of the new
        // fragment is exactly
        // such a frame
        for (Track track : tracks) {
            if (track.getSyncSamples() != null
                    && track.getSyncSamples().length > 0) {
                if (timeCorrected) {
                    // This exception here could be a false positive in case we
                    // have multiple tracks
                    // with sync samples at exactly the same positions. E.g. a
                    // single movie containing
                    // multiple qualities of the same video (Microsoft Smooth
                    // Streaming file)

                    throw new RuntimeException(
                            "The startTime has already been corrected by another track with SyncSample. Not Supported.");

            }
        }

        for (Track track : tracks) {
            long currentSample = 0;
            double currentTime = 0;
            long startSample = -1;
            long endSample = -1;

            for (int i = 0; i < track.getDecodingTimeEntries().size(); i++) {
                TimeToSampleBox.Entry entry = track.getDecodingTimeEntries().get(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < entry.getCount(); j++) {
                    // entry.getDelta() is the amount of time the current sample
                    // covers.

                    if (currentTime <= startTime) {
                        // current sample is still before the new starttime
                        startSample = currentSample;
                    }
                    if (currentTime <= endTime) {
                        // current sample is after the new start time and still
                        // before the new endtime
                        endSample = currentSample;
                    } else {
                        // current sample is after the end of the cropped video
                        break;
                    }
                    currentTime += (double) entry.getDelta()
                            / (double) track.getTrackMetaData().getTimescale();
                    currentSample++;
                }
            }
            movie.addTrack(new CroppedTrack(track, startSample, endSample));
        }

        IsoFile out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(movie);

        String filePath = "sdcard/test"+i+".mp4";
        i++;
        File f = new File(filePath);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 65535);
        out.getBox(new IsoOutputStream(bos));
        bos.close();
        fos.close();

    }
```

P.S:-I am not much familiar with this code but some how am able to trim video but it shows error in last.

Answer (score 2):

You should "normalize" your start and stop values them to correspond to mp4 sync samples, otherwise you'll get some glitches on an output video or even broken file.

Please have a look at `correctTimeToSyncSample` method:

1. [Android Gallery source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/android-4.2.2_r1/src/com/android/gallery3d/app/TrimVideoUtils.java) (uses mp4parser 0.9.x, I guess)
2. [My sample project](https://gitlab.com/lassana/mp4parser-test/blob/master/src/com/github/lassana/mp4parser_test/Mp4Cutter2.java) (uses mp4parser 1.1.18).

```
private static double correctTimeToSyncSample(Track track, double cutHere, boolean next) {
    double[] timeOfSyncSamples = new double[track.getSyncSamples().length];
    long currentSample = 0;
    double currentTime = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i = 0) {
            timeOfSyncSamples[Arrays.binarySearch(track.getSyncSamples(), currentSample + 1)] = currentTime;
        }
        currentTime += (double) delta / (double) track.getTrackMetaData().getTimescale();
        currentSample++;
    }
    double previous = 0;
    for (double timeOfSyncSample : timeOfSyncSamples) {
        if (timeOfSyncSample > cutHere) {
            if (next) {
                return timeOfSyncSample;
            } else {
                return previous;
            }
        }
        previous = timeOfSyncSample;
    }
    return timeOfSyncSamples[timeOfSyncSamples.length - 1];
}
```

Usage:

```
for (Track track : tracks) {
    if (track.getSyncSamples() != null && track.getSyncSamples().length > 0) {
        if (timeCorrected) {
            throw new RuntimeException("The startTime has already been corrected by another track with SyncSample. Not Supported.");
        }
        startTime = correctTimeToSyncSample(track, startTime, false);
        endTime = correctTimeToSyncSample(track, endTime, true);
        timeCorrected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the delta and for loop is not correct

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the position which you want to cut is at the middle of an Iframe. I'm facing a similar problem. I can not cut exactly where I want, because at the begin of video I get bad frames. Did you get bad frames at the begin of trimmed video?

Comment: No nothing like that. Actually now am up and running with my code. :)

Comment: So you mean that you can cut exactly where you want with the code above?

Comment: @Rohit what was the change in your code that made it to work ?

Comment: @Sunshinetpu it was 30 seconds

Comment: @Sunshinetpu how did you modify the Iframe interval?